# loopback external methods are slow

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have added a remote method to my Image model. Everything used to work well until i decided to update the loopback npm package.

The remote method is very slow and I can see the following pending request in the network tab.

[image]

I don't know what exactly has changed; I even re-installed the npm packages I had when everything was running well but the issue is still there.

I tried added some breakpoints to my remote method as well, but it takes some time to hit them.

It seems like there is a cpu bound operation that blocks the thread.

Comment: Can't really say one way or the other until you include some code examples. Just a shot in the dark until then.

Comment: Pending status means no response at all.

Comment: @IvanZh pending status means the server is still working on the request and that's the problem I'm trying to resolve

Comment: @Brian I fixed that by switching to the older versions of the loopback packages. I think there is something wrong with the latest mongodb connector.